# Upgrade .netstandard 1.6 to 2.0 but still work for .net core 1.1

Tags: .net, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

**TL;DR**
How can the old projects (*not compatible with .netstandard2.0*) still make use of the existing functionality provided by the class library which is upgraded from .netstandard 1.6 to .netstandard 2.0?

Say I created a .net standard 1.6 Class Library A and the library is used by both .net core 1.1 applications and .net core 2.0 application.

```
+---.net core 1.1
     +---ClassLibraryA (.netstandard1.6)
+---.net core 2.0
     +---ClassLibraryA (.netstandard1.6)
```

However, there's a new requirement which requires the BinaryFormatter. As the .net standard 1.6 doesn't support it, so I upgrade the Class Library A to .net standard 2.0.

But, as you may know, the .net standard 2.0 is not supported by the .net core 1.1. So, **how can I solve this problem if I can't upgrade the .net core 1.1 application to .net core 2.0 due to some other reasons?**

The only solution I came up with is to create another project say B which is a .net standard 2.0 project and copy all the code to this project. But, I think the solution is ugly.

The ugly solution:

```
+---.net core 1.1
     +---ClassLibraryA (.netstandard1.6)
+---.net core 2.0
     +---ClassLibraryB (.netstandard2.0) //Copy codes from ClassLibrary1.6
```

*Note, I just take the BinaryFormatter for an example.*

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the .NET Standard version is not going to make [`BinaryFormatter`](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter) available to projects built on an older version of the runtime/standard.

If you cannot upgrade the .NET Core 1.1 project then you might drop in the functionality by vetting open source libraries like [lukasz-pyrzyk/BinaryFormatter](https://github.com/lukasz-pyrzyk/BinaryFormatter/) or segregating the new functionality to a another project targeting a version of .NET that supports `BinaryFormatter`.

Comment: Thanks Romoku, however, I just take the BinaryFormatter as an example and I won't introduce another third party library to my solution. I have updated my question to be more specific.